# Как сделать в yii2 консольное обращение

Tags: php, yii2

Как сделать в *Yii2* консольное обращение?
Господа прошу подсказать

1. установил на *OpenServer* фреймворк *YII2 basic*, вижу тестовый сайт (mysite.local)
2. открываю CMD, перехожу в URL моего сайта (c:\My\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\mysite.local>_ )
3. ввожу

   ```
   yii <hello> [-m=hello]
   ```

   получаю

   > Не удается найти указанный файл.

Как обычно, проблема открытия для себя нового. Подскажите, как сделать в *Yii2* консольное обращение?

UPD

при php yii попадаю на

```html
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\My\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\mysite.local\vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\functions.php on line 78
```

**ввожу команду ест-но без скобок**

Comment: тут много нюансов. вы набираете именно так, как написали? Т.е. `yii <hello> [-m=hello]` со всеми скобками? Потому что надо без них...Вы в папке `console` создали `HelloController` ? что в нем написано?

Comment: ест-но без скобок, файл ест-но создал по образу и подобию http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html#options-aliases

Comment: `при php yii попадаю на Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['` - Версия PHP должна быть >= 5.4

Comment: пробовал на 5.5/5.6

Comment: ну это относительно ошибки парсинга..... должно работать с 5.5/5.6........ а версия фреймворка какая? можно посмотреть так: `Yii::getVersion();`

Comment: в консоле PHP=5.3 Корень зла найден! ( хотя в OpenServer выставлено 5.6 ) Сейчас буду думать как менять

Comment: лучше 100% посмотреть версию через `echo Yii::getVersion();` в php файле ........... и 100% посмотреть версию PHP через консоль `php -v` ......

Comment: ну вот..... надо в модулях поменять версию и попробовать перезагрузить даже комп......вдруг поможет......... а может от админа надо запускать :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны создать в папке `app/commands` файл `HelloController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace app\commands;

use yii\console\Controller;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public $message;

    public function options($actionID)
    {
        return ['message'];
    }

    public function optionAliases()
    {
        return ['m' => 'message'];
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo $this->message . "\n";
    }
}
```

И только тогда ваша команда отработает.
Скорее всего вы читали [официальный гайд](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html#create-command) но не дочитали или что-то ещё, пробуйте.

Comment: файл именно такой! вот не понимаю из за чего не работает

Comment: решение такое: открываем консоль OpenServer, т.к. в CMD версия PHP 5,3!

Comment: @serg может до openserver что-то стояло и прописалось в переменные среды?, логично что при работе с openserver нужно использовать консоль именно его..... либо в переменные среды прописывать путь до нужной версии >_<